# Changing the start up location of a WPF window in XAML to Bottom-Right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to set the manual startup location for a WPF window in XAML to start in the *Bottom-Right* corner of the screen? I can do it in code-behind, but when the window opens, it pops up at the manual location (middle-left of the screen) then it jumps to the bottom right of the screen and it does not look very good.

I can set the location in the Top-Left of the corner in XAML with this coding:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="Window1" 
    Height="500" Width="500"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual" 
    Left="0" Top="0">
</Window>
```

Can I do the same for the Bottom-Right corner of the screen with XAML coding to fit ANY screen size?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done in XAML only, but you could always hide the window and then show it after you have moved it to the right position to avoid that "jump".

Comment: @NemanjaBanda Thats a great idea! I didn't even think of that ;P How would I hide the window? I used `this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` but it gave me an error.

Comment: What event are you using? Works fine for me if I put `Visibility="Collapsed"` in XAML and then `this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible` in `ContentRendered` event.

Comment: @NemanjaBanda Thanks for the effort man, but Gopichandar's solution worked out for me and I do not have to hide it anymore. :)

Comment: Great, no problem, never hurts to know more than one way to do something though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is not possible to set it via `xaml`.  But, You can set it even before the window got loaded that wont jumps from manual location.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Left = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width;
    Top = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `WindowStartupLocation="Manual"` in `XAML`.

Then in `Window_Loaded` set the position like,

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
    this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, but as I mentioned in my original question, I've already tried this and the window jumps from the manual location to the bottom-right of the screen. It does not look very nice.